# Will elasticsearch snapshot remove data after a index been deleted?

Tags: elasticsearch

We have some data that goes wrong and been snapshot into daily snapshot. I understand that the Snapshot is incremental. I am wondering if there is any easy way to remove those incorrect data/index from snapshot without delete and re-take snapshot?

Will retake snapshot on same indices remove deleted indices(?)

Comment: Not possible. You need to delete the documents and then take another snapshot.

Comment: Thank you Andrei, it is really painful to delete one snapshot and spend another 5 hours to retake it. Buy anyway, if that is only solution.

Comment: I didn't say to delete the snapshot. I said to delete the wrong data from your index, then take another snapshot. The new snapshot will not have the wrong data. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Trying to remove wrong data (it's very large) from daily snapshot. Isn't snapshot incrementally and old snapshot will still include wrong data index and spending unnecessary disk space? Because the data was incorrect, so it's not necessary to keep it in snapshot which will cost us around 1TB disk space. We need to remove that index and free this 1TB

Comment: Yes, it is incremental and using disk space. Do you want to keep old snapshots around? If not, you can delete individual snapshots where the data is wrong and keep recent snapshots where the data was updated.

Comment: Okay, thanks, yea, thats what I am doing.